# How can I populate 2 arraylist of different size with custom adapter?

Tags: android

I want to populate 2 arraylist of different size with Base Adapter in such a way that:

- I am having Arraylist of 2 images and second Arraylist of string having 3 names.
- I want to set 1st 2 image with 1st 2 names but for the 3rd name repeat the 1st image and so on.

Please suggest, Thanks in advance.

This is my Activity:

```
name.add("aestro"); 
name.add("blender"); 
name.add("cup_cake");
img.add(R.drawable.nougat); 
img.add(R.drawable.marshmallow); 
listView.setAdapter(new My_ada(MainActivity.this,name,img));
```

Section of Adapter where I am trying to set data:

```
 view_holder.textView.setText(Name.get(i)); 
if(Img.size()<Name.size()){ 
    for(int x=0;x<Name.size();x++){ 
        view_holder.textView.setText(Name.get(i)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Always 3 items will there.

Comment: for that you'll have to save images on the positions

Comment: you need to make one ArrayList form two of them

Comment: post your adapter code here

Comment: this is my Activity:

Comment: name.add("aestro");
        name.add("blender");
        name.add("cup_cake");

        img.add(R.drawable.nougat);
        img.add(R.drawable.marshmallow);


       listView.setAdapter(new My_ada(MainActivity.this,name,img));

Comment: Section of Adapter where I am trying to set data:

            view_holder.textView.setText(Name.get(i));
            if(Img.size()<Name.size()){
                for(int x=0;x<Name.size();x++){
                    view_holder.textView.setText(Name.get(i));
                }
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for Json that you provide you can make one object or you can make two arraylist.I am posting solution for two arraylist

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private View view;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> names;
    ArrayList<String> images;

    public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> img) {
        this.context=context;
        names=names;
// make images equals to names
    for (int i = names.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
    String a=imgs.get(names%imgs);
    images.add(a)
}
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_list,parent,false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final CustomViewHolder= (CustomViewHolder) holder;
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(names.get(position));
         Glide.with(context)
                .load(images.get(positon))
                .asBitmap()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_user)
                .into(viewHolder.ivImage);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return names.size();
    }
    private class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView ivImage;
        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            tvTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            ivImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_img);

        }

    }

}
```

I hope this will work and if you have doubts on Glide let me know.

Comment: But what if the data is coming from Json, (It was a hardoced sample). I mean if the string arraylist > image arraylist then how could I set them in the above way so that images can repeat after last image set with respect to the strings?

Comment: you just need to save path of that image in arraylist and u can use glide,fresco or any other image loading library to show image can you post json that is coming i can give solution.

Comment: That's the problem I am not allowed to post Json. I am trying your way. Thank you

Comment: then post dummy json don't use actual values just key and value-type

Comment: { 
"worldpopulation": 
 [
   {
   "country":"China",   "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/china.png"
   }, 
  
   {
   "country":"India",   "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/india.png"
   }, 
   
   {
  "country":"United States",
 "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/unitedstates.png"
   }, 
   
   {
   "country":"Indonesia",   "flag":"http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/flag/indonesia.png"
   }, 
   
   {
   "country":"Brazil"
   }, 
  
   {
   "country":"Japan"
   }

               
 ] 
}

Comment: now in the listview output Brazil should have "china flag" and japan should have "India-flag"

Comment: i guess u have parsed this data and made two arraylist and you just need to show and is this list going dynamic or static.

Comment: Yeah all set just need that logic which can repeat the images.

Comment: I have posted the answer check it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Create Arraylist of object instead of two separate list.

```
class Holder{
private int image1 // integer if it is drawable image
private int image2
.... // add all things
}
```

use objects of this class in arraylist and use it.

```
Arraylist<Holder> holders = new Arraylist<>();
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do it that way??? You only need one arraylist.

You can create a class, like so.

```
class Person {

    String word, image;

    public Person(String word, String image) {
        this.word = word;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return this.word;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

}
```

After that, you can do some code like this

```
ArrayList<Person> listPerson = new ArrayList<Person> ();
listPerson.add(new Person("word1", "image1"));
listPerson.add(new Person("word1", "image2"));
listPerson.add(new Person("word2", "image2"));
listPerson.add(new Person("word3", "image1"));


for (int i = 0; i < listPerson.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("WORD -> " + listPerson.get(i).getWord() + " IMAGE -> " + listPerson.get(i).getImage());
}
```

And finally, your output would be....

```
WORD -> word1 IMAGE -> image1
WORD -> word1 IMAGE -> image2
WORD -> word2 IMAGE -> image2
WORD -> word3 IMAGE -> image1
```

This will allow you to control the word and the image. So word1 can be the same for image1 and image2. etc etc

If you were putting this into a listview or grid view, itll all come together nicely. dont overthink that part. :)

Comment: But what if the data is coming from Json, (It was a hardoced sample). I mean if the string arraylist > image arraylist then how could I set them in the above way so that images can repeat after last image
 set with respect to the strings?

Comment: You can still push the information into the arraylist as a string. That wouldnt matter. Do you know how to parse from a json file? If so, you store the values as strings and insert them into a list the same way I did.